# Usage of plural "maximums" in "I tried to go for six maximums"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, nouns

> After his Man of the Match performance, Rohit appeared on the Chahal TV, hosted by leg-spinner Yuzvendra Chahal, and revealed the mantra for hitting sixes.
>
> “**When I hit three consecutive sixes, I tried to go for six maximums**. But when I missed the fourth one, I decided I will take singles,” said Rohit while speaking about his three consecutive sixes which he hit against off-spinner Mosaddek Hossain.
>
> <sub>Hindustan Times: [‘I tried to go for six sixes but...’ Rohit Sharma reveals what changed his mind](https://www.hindustantimes.com/cricket/i-tried-to-go-for-six-sixes-but-rohit-sharma-reveals-what-changed-his-mind/story-edVPY3gGDwHfj7PYY2E9SO.html)</sub>

This  is  a  piece  of  news  paper  report  published  online  in India. It  is  a quote  from the  player.

I have  searched  on Google  to  find  out  whether  the 
word  maximum   can be used  as  plural  noun but I  could  not  find  it. I think  it  is  an abstract noun and  so  it  can not  be  used  in the  plural number.

Here  is  a  link.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maximum

The  link  shows  that  maximum is  usually  singular  and  its  plural  form  is  maximums. 
I think  in the sentence  it  should  be  six  sixers. I am doubtful  of  the  use  maximums  in the  sentence.

> ** can the  word  *maximum*  be  used  as  a  plural noun as  in the  given sentence**?

Comment: @ Rohit  sarma  meant  only  sixers. He  can not  imagine  a no ball  to  be  bowled.

Comment: Please copy the text accurately and provide the source. That's where I found it, so I'm assuming that's the source.

Comment: The question should be "Can the word 'maximums' be used..." and not "Is the word 'maximums' can be used..."

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.

First "can 'a maximum' mean 'a six-run hit' in cricket jargon?" The answer to that is 'yes, in context'.  If you said:

> I hit a maximum on the last ball of the over.

(and it was clear that you were talking about cricket, to someone who understands the rules of the game) then it would be understood. So "a maximum" in a cricket context can mean "a six-run hit".

As for the plural: there are two possibilities "maxima" or "maximums". In maths and science we would often say "the local maxima of the function" when talking about the peaks of a graph

> The cos(x) graph has maxima at 0 and 360 degrees, and minima at +-180 degrees.

But in less formal contexts, such as in sport or in spoken English, the regular plural "maximums" is more common. So Rohit's use of English is correct and appropriate to the context. This particular usage is specific to cricket and is a little casual, so probably isn't in regular dictionaries yet.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can the word **"maximum"** be used as a plural noun as in the given sentence?*

Yes, it can be used in its plural form.

In cricket, the *maximum* a batsman can score from a single ball is six points (i.e., *six runs*). When a batsman does that, it is called *"hitting a six"*. Since there are 6 balls in an *over*, the batsman can hit 6 sixes (this gives him a total of *thirty-six runs*).

In your case, the batsman had intended to hit 6 sixes. And because *"six"* is the maximum, it is idiomatic to say both

> *"I tried to go for 6 sixes"*

and

> *"I tried to go for 6 maximums"*

I suspect he just wasn't comfortable saying "six sixes". Furthermore, it is colloquial to say "maximum" when referring to *"hitting a six"* in cricket. There are many instances of its use in google news (sports news: cricket). Here are two:

> *"Scoring 56 (62), he hit three boundaries and two **maximums**."* - [CT 2017, Match 6: ENG v NZ – 5 Game Changing Moments](https://www.crictracker.com/ct-2017-match-6-eng-v-nz-5-game-changing-moments/)
>
> *"Malan reached three figures in just 48 balls to become only England’s second centurion in the format, smashing nine fours and six **maximums**."* - [Malan reacts to setting England record in crushing T20 win over New Zealand](https://metro.co.uk/2019/11/08/dawid-malan-reacts-setting-england-record-crushing-t20-win-new-zealand-11066102/)

---

Okay, now with cricket out of the way, the plural "maximums" can be (and is) used in many other scenarios.

> *The maximum employer and employee contribution to the CPP for next year will be $2,898 each, and the maximum self-employed contribution will be $5,796. The **maximums** in 2019 were $2,748.90 and $5,497.80, respectively.* - [CPP maximum pensionable earnings for 2020](https://www.advisor.ca/tax/tax-news/cra-sets-cpp-maximum-pensionable-earnings-for-2020/)
>
> *"In the previous section we were asked to find and classify all critical points as relative **minimums**, relative **maximums** and/or saddle points."* - google